# How can I verify whether or not Windows Server 2008 R2 has SP1 installed?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service-pack

Usually Windows shows SPX on the System Information screen - is that the case for Windows Server 2008 R2? Is this a reliable way to verify whether or not SP1 is installed on this machine?

[image: Windows Server 2008 R2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WinKey+R, enter `winver` It will print Version 6.1 (Compilation 7601: Service Pack 1)

And no, your installation doesn't have SP1 installed (it adds a 3rd line to version section)

Answer (score 5):

The command `winver` will give you What you need.[image]